# How find the n the number of power php

Tags: php, math

With the number power of 2 something like:

```
 2^n = 16
```

How can we find the `n` within the php?

thanks

Comment: [Read the documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.log.php)

Comment: take the log or 2^n=16 can be expressed as 2^n=2^4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
 $x = 1024;
 $num = 2;
 $y = log($x, $num);
 echo $y;
?>
```

gives y=10

Answer (score 2):

[`log()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.log.php) takes a base argument.

`log(16, 2)` is `4`.